# Android app won't query database from android device , but works fine on emulator

Tags: java, php, android

I've created a android app which the user enters text into two text boxes , clicks search, then it starts a new activity where it displays the results in a recycler view.
I am using android studio, a passing the user inputs as variables using GET into my PHP where I am querying based on this.

Example:

```
Select year from database where something = 'parameter1' and something ='parameter2';
```

This works fine in emulator when I run it, but when I run on my android device it just returns a blank list where the results should be.
Anyone know what this could be?
Really appreciate any suggestions to try.

Comment: My first guess is INTERNET permission. Could you provide some code and more details?

Comment: In any chance you have developer server on your machine (localhost)?  Ping your server from the device to make sure that this is reachable and this is correct server (in case you have both developer and production servers running)